# Почему Soap ошибка?

Tags: php, soap, soapui

Отправляю запрос в SoapUI и он мне выводит ошибку при вызове метода. Но если пройти по данный ссылке то в браузере все выдается.
ошибка

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://api.ghk.dev.b2pos.ru/loan/wsdl.php' : failed to load external entity "https://api.ghk.dev.b2pos.ru/loan/wsdl.php"

Помогите пожалуйста. Почему он не может его загрузить ?
Мне надо отправить запрос через SoapUI

Comment: Версия SoapUI - 5.5.0. Никакой ошибки при загрузке не возникло.

Comment: Попробуйте включить или выклюить прокси в настройках

Comment: у меня такая же версия. вы получили методы но вот отправить если запрос то получите такую ошибку

Comment: включал и выключал прокси